# While publishing in anchor registry it shows Failed to obtain package metadata and doesn't build

Tags: anchor

When i try to anchor publish this error appears any idea on how to resolve this. WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested 596cf01fc8c5a502dc0d282c5eb25519628cbb59186ca1e696f19f76b396d6e7 Building zebec manifest: "programs/zebec/Cargo.toml" Failed to obtain package metadata: cargo metadata exited with an error: Updating crates.io index Cleaning up the docker target directory Removing the docker container anchor-program Error during Docker build: Failed to build program Error: Failed to build program